# How to delete objects on a Thymeleaf th:each iteration passing an ID to the controller?

Tags: rest, controller, each, thymeleaf

My controller:

```
@GetMapping("/deletesocio/{id}")
public String delSocios(@PathVariable Long id){
    socioSer.borrar(socioService.buscarPorId(id));
    return "redirect:/webapp/socios";
}
```

My HTML

```
<tr th:each="soc : ${list}">
    <td th:text="${soc.idSocio}">#</td>
    <td th:text="${soc.nombreSocio}">Nombre</td>
    <td class="button778"><button type="button" 
    th:href="@{/webapp/delsocio/${soc.idSocio}}"></button></td>
</tr>
```

I want to delete the object by clicking this button who pass de id to the controller (well, thats the idea), could any one help me please?? thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this...

1) The url expressions you should use is: `@{/webapp/delsocio/{id}(id=${soc.idSocio})}`

2) You can either make it a form with a submit button or style a regular link as a button [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906586/4126893).  Whichever solution you decide on will determine if you use `th:action="@{/webapp/delsocio/{id}(id=${soc.idSocio})}"` or `th:href="@{/webapp/delsocio/{id}(id=${soc.idSocio})}"`.

Comment: Id like to use it without a form... should I have to put at that button a th:method? the url has to be with a th:href? What about the controller? It's getmaping? o maybe postmaping? I dont know why isn't still works

Comment: If you want to do it without a form, then create a link and style it to look like a button (the post I linked to shows how to do that).  In that case, the controller should be @GetMapping.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't remembered I need a link for make the button works, this gave me 6 hours xD