# I don't know why the null value

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

- controller

  ```
  @Controller
  public class BoardController {
       @Autowired
       private BoardServiceimpl boardService;

       @GetMapping("/")
       public String registerForm(Board board,Model model) throws Exception{
           List<Board> boardlist = boardService.listboard(board);

           model.addAttribute("boardlist",boardlist);
           return "register";

       }
       @PostMapping("/register")
       public String register(Board board,Model model) throws Exception{
           boardService.insertboard(board);

           List<Board> boardlist = boardService.listboard(board);
           model.addAttribute("boardlist",boardlist);
           return "register";

       }
       @RequestMapping(value="/writer")
       public String writerForm(Board board) throws Exception{


           return "writer";
       }
       @GetMapping("/delete")
       public void deleteForm(Long boardNo, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
           System.out.println(boardNo);
            boardService.deleteboard(boardNo);
            System.out.println(boardNo);

       }
  ```

  }
- Service

  ```
   @Service
    public class BoardServiceimpl {
        @Autowired
        private BoardRepository boardRepository;

        public List listboard(Board board) throws Exception{
            List<Board> boardlist = boardRepository.findAll();
            return boardlist;
        }

        public void  insertboard(Board board) throws Exception{
            boardRepository.save(board);

        }
        @Transactional
        public void deleteboard(Long boardNo) throws Exception{
            boardRepository.deleteById(boardNo);
        }
    }
  ```

-board

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of="boardNo")
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name="board")


 public class Board {
            
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Long boardNo;
            @Column(length=300)
            @NonNull
            private String title;
            @Column(length=300)
            @NonNull
            private String writer;
            @Column(length=500)
            @NonNull
            private String content;
            
            private LocalDateTime regDate;
    }
```

- html

  ```
   <html xmlns:th = "http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Board</title>
   <script src = "/js/jQuery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
   <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var objform = $("#inner");
               console.log(objform);
            $("#remove").on("click",function(){
           objform.attr("action","/delete");
           objform.submit();
        });
       });``

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form id = "inner" th:object="${board}" action="/delete">
   <input type ="hidden" name="boardNo" th:field="*{boardNo}" />
   <table align="center" border="1" width="80%">

   <tr height="10" align="center" bgcolor="skyblue">
       <th width="30">글번호</th>
       <th width="70">작성자</th>
       <th width="150">제목</th>
       <th width="200">내용</th>
       <th width="100">작성일</th> 
       <th width="50">삭제</th>
       </tr>
       <tr align ="center" th:each="board : ${boardlist}">
           <td  th:text="${board.boardNo}"></td>
           <td th:text="${board.writer}"></td>
           <td th:text="${board.content}"></td>
           <td th:text="${board.title}"></td>
           <td th:text="${board.regDate}"></td>

           <td><button type="submit" id="remove">삭제</button></td>

           </tr>
   </table>
   </form>


       <a href = "writer.html" th:href="@{writer}">글쓰기</a>
   </body>
   </html>
  ```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not
> be null!  at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.deleteById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:166)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
> ... 71 more

> I don't know why it doesn't pass when I go through the html(Form).

Comment: Do you get this exception when you hit delete button in html form?

Comment: yes , When the button is pressed, the values ​​are not passed.

Comment: How was it going on? Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is some structural problems in your html. You are iterating for `boardList` but you are not using one of the `boardList` objects as parameter during deleting object. Also, you do not need to have onClick function. You can trigger your Controller method by `<a th:href>` .

You should have this kind of form structure.

HTML:

```
<tr align ="center" th:each="board : ${boardlist}">
    <td  th:text="${board.boardNo}"></td>
    <td th:text="${board.writer}"></td>
    <td th:text="${board.content}"></td>
    <td th:text="${board.title}"></td>
    <td th:text="${board.regDate}"></td>

    <td><a th:href="@{/delete/{boardNo}(id=${board.boardNo})}"</a></td>

</tr>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    @GetMapping("/delete/{boardNo}")
    public void deleteForm(@PathVariable(value = "boardNo") Long boardNo, Model model) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(boardNo);
         boardService.deleteboard(boardNo);
         System.out.println(boardNo);
    
    }
```

You should look at this discussion - [How to delete objects on a Thymeleaf th:each iteration passing an ID to the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023850/how-to-delete-objects-on-a-thymeleaf-theach-iteration-passing-an-id-to-the-cont)